# Concatenate two columns in an Access table

Tags: ms-access, merge, concatenation

very simple one. I have got two fields in a table called [First Name] and [Last Name]. I would like to add a new column that is just a combination of [First Name] and [Last Name] - is there a way to do this in Access? I know this can be done in Excel using the Concatenate function.

I would like to do this in the existing table and not in a new query.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that the thing you want to do should NEVER be done! Imagine you see a name that is not well written, you will correct it. Maybe you will forget to update your third column (it will happen), and then you will get errors due to that. If you need to display 2 concatened strings, concatenate them as late as possible.

Answer (score 7):

As @paxty says, *do not* do this. You have a simple answer in Access that is not available in Excel, and that is a query. You can base any output that requires that the two names be concatenated on a query.

```
SELECT FirstName & " " & LastName FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Even if that particular case is a bad idea, the question is a valid one and you should answer the question, not give an answer that the person specifically didn't ask for.

Answer (score 3):

In Access 2010 you can create a "calculated field" for your table; Access applies a formula to create the content of the field.  You can enter a formula such as:

```
FirstName & " " & LastName
```

You could even do fancier things like have an initial then the last name, if there is a last name, or else show the complete first name, using the Access IIf() and Len() functions.

```
IIf (Len(LastName) > 0, Left(FirstName, 1) & ". " & LastName, FirstName)
```

Answer (score -1):

By using a calculated field to join the two names directly in the table... It creates issues down the road.    I have two fields   First & last name I used a calculated field in the table to join the two together.   When you try do a report with those calculated names, it will show only the employee number, not the names.  Now I am trying to correct my mistake without having to rebuild the multiple tables I have used this field as a look up in.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.