# Showing currently selected field in a separate textbox in Access

Tags: ms-access, activerecord, textbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHpkX.png)

I'm relatively new to Access and I've come unstuck.

I've put together a form where I can drill down into the academic interests of academics with key words. I'd like to be able to show the contents of interest_A, interest_b, and interest_C of  the selected record/row in the Text15 text box at the bottom of the image and for that to change automatically if I selected another record/row.

If this is possible, then I might hide interest_A, interest_b, and interest_C from view of the user and just have them visible in Text15

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've looked around for advice or tutorials but haven't found anything on this issue.

Comment: Are interest A, interest B, interest C three fields of same record? If yes, then just expression in textbox to concatenate fields. If no and each interest is a record, then you need VBA. Edit question to show sample data as a formatted text table.

Comment: Assuming the drill down is based on the forms record source: For Example, Text15.ControlSource= Interest_A & " " & Interest_B & " " & Interest_C

Comment: Oh, I did not notice the image link. Simple concatenation. Although, will end up with extra spaces if interest B or C are empty. And a comma might make it easier to read but again, don't want extra commas if fields are empty. Use a mix of + and & for concatenation. `Interest_A & ", " + Interest_B & ", " + Interest_C`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate two columns in an Access table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975197/concatenate-two-columns-in-an-access-table)

Comment: Review https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/combine-text-values-by-using-an-expression-d1653b60-dd60-4a05-9747-6b31ba4c4eed